# get maximum sum of consecutive elements in an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to get the maximum sum of three consecutive elements in an array and the index of the starting element of the maximum sum.

In a given array,

```
int a[] = {2,1,3,2,4,6,7,9,1}
```

maximum `sum = 6 + 7 + 9 = 22`
starting index of maximum sum is `5` (index of the starting item -`6`).

I have written the code as below but it's not performance efficient. Not sure if using *Linq* gives better results

Could anyone please suggest any better approach.

```
private static int[] getConsecutiveSum(int[] a, int k)
        {
            List<int> lst = new List<int>();
            for (int x = 0; x < a.Length; x++)
            {
                lst.Add(getsum(a, x, k));
            }

            var max = lst[0];
            var index = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i <lst.Count; i++)
            {
                if(lst[i] > max)
                {
                    max = lst[i];
                    index = i;
                }
            }
            int[] result = new int[2];
            result[0] = max;
            result[1] = index;
            return result;
        }

        private static int getsum(int[] a, int s, int e)
        {
            var sum = 0;
            var loop = 1;
            for (int x = s; x < a.Length; x++)
            {
                sum = sum + a[x];
                loop++;
                if (loop > e) break;
            }
            if (loop > e) return sum;
            else return 0;
        }
}
```

Comment: just go through every number until the last minus the amount of consecutives you want to get. and then just add the numbers every time, if the sum is higher -> save the index and the sum, if not -> continue. Whats so hard about that? Your code seems really slow because you do unnecessary stuff

Comment: int a[] = {2,1,3,2,4,6,7,9,1} is an array declaration? Someone please fix that first.

Comment: Do you need to handle `int.MaxValue` and `int.MinValue` as possible values in the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want any *collection* (`list`) to find the maximum; we have to *scan* the array only. Since we want to return `2` values, let's use `Tuple<int, int>` as a simplest implementation

```
private static Tuple<int, int> getMaxSum(int[] a, int k) {
  int sum = a.Take(k).Sum();
  int max = sum;
  int index = 0;

  for (int i = k; i < a.Length; ++i) {
    sum = sum - a[i - k] + a[i];

    if (sum > max) {
      max = sum;
      index = i - k + 1;
    }
  }

  return Tuple.Create(max, index);
}

...

int a[] = new int[] {
  2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 1};

var result = getMaxSum(a, 3);

Console.Write($"Sum is {result.Item1}; starting index is {result.Item2}");
```

Outcome

```
Sum is 22; starting index is 5
```

Comment: `(int max, int index)` named tuples are the awesomness

Comment: @TheGeneral: you are quite right, thank you! However named tupples appeared in C# 7.0 only, that's why (what if OP uses 6th or even 4th version?) I implemented it as `Tupple<int, int>`

Answer (score 1):

It will be more performance effective without using Linq. Since you want two values from the method, you can use `out` parameters:

```
private static void GetConsecutiveSum(int[] values, out int maximumSum, out int startIndex)
{
    maximumSum = 0;
    startIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length - 2; i++)
    {
        int sequenceSum = values[i] + values[i + 1] + values[i + 2];
        if (sequenceSum > maximumSum)
        {
            maximumSum = sequenceSum;
            startIndex = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: or you can return a tuple

Answer (score 0):

Well, in LINQ it will be something like this:

```
var result = a.Select((s, i) => new { Sum = a.Skip(i).Take(3).Sum(), Index = i })
              .OrderByDescending(o => o.Sum)
              .First();

Console.WriteLine($"MaxSum: {result.Sum}, StartIndex: {result.Index}");
```

Output:

> MaxSum: 22, StartIndex: 5

For your task, it will look like so:

```
private static int[] getConsecutiveSum(int[] a, int k)
{
    int[] result = new int[2];
    var maxSum = a.Select((s, i) => new { Sum = a.Skip(i).Take(k).Sum(), Index = i })
                  .OrderByDescending(o => o.Sum)
                  .First();
    result[0] = maxSum.Sum;
    result[1] = maxSum.Index;
    return result;
}
```

I've not changed your method's return type from `int[]` to tuple or something, because if it is a some online coding challenge or something, then I guess you are not allowed to change return type of the method (to making code checking automation possible).